# In Clojure how can I make a HoneySQL query that generates SQL to insert a value in a table field that have and enum type?

Tags: postgresql, clojure, honeysql

Let's take for instance this table created in postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE public.item (
id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
"size_type" public."size_type" NULL)
```

and this data type:

```
CREATE TYPE public."size_type" AS ENUM (
'small',
'medium',
'large');
```

What I want to do is to generate with HoneySQL the following SQL query for insert the value 'small' into the "size_type" field of the item table

`INSERT INTO item ("size_type") VALUES ('small'::size_type);`

I am using this approach:

`{:insert-into :item :values [{:size_type "small"}]}`

But I am getting this mismatch error:

> "message": "Conflict: Uncaught PSQL exception: ERROR: column "size_type" is of type size_type but expression is of type character varying\n  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.\n  Position: 172",
> "psql-error-type": "DATATYPE_MISMATCH"

Comment: HoneySQL does not execute SQL so this question doesn't make sense as asked.

HoneySQL generates SQL from a data structure so you need to know what SQL you want to generate first, and then you can ask "How do I generate this SQL with HoneySQL?"

Comment: True. What I meant is how to write a query with honeysql dsl that generates a sql to insert a enum value into the table above. I am using this approach: {:insert-into :item
              :values  [{:size_type "small"}]}.  After executing this code with next.jdbc  execute! I got "DATATYPE_MISMATCH" error.

Comment: First of all, you need to figure out what the SQL needs to be -- take HoneySQL out of the equation and get your SQL working first.

Comment: this is the sql I want to generate: INSERT INTO item ("size_type") VALUES ('small'::size_type);

Comment: Can you update your question to reflect what you're really asking at this point? i.e., specifying the SQL you want and asking how to generate it with HoneySQL.

Otherwise it will get closed as a poorly-worded question.

Comment: You can use `:cast` if the value is not known statically, or `:inline` if it is.

Answer (score 0):

As Eugene said in his comment, what you need is `:cast` -- here's a few possible approaches, showing the SQL that would be generated in each case:

```
user=> (require '[honey.sql :as sql])
nil
user=> (sql/format {:insert-into :item :values [{:size_type [:cast "small" :size_type]}]})
["INSERT INTO item (size_type) VALUES (CAST(? AS SIZE_TYPE))" "small"]
user=> (sql/format {:insert-into :item :values [{:size_type [:cast "small" :public.size_type]}]})
["INSERT INTO item (size_type) VALUES (CAST(? AS PUBLIC.SIZE_TYPE))" "small"]
user=> (sql/format {:insert-into :item :values [{:size_type [:cast "small" :'public.size_type]}]})
["INSERT INTO item (size_type) VALUES (CAST(? AS public.size_type))" "small"]
user=> (sql/format {:insert-into :item :values [{:size_type [:cast [:inline "small"] :'public.size_type]}]})
["INSERT INTO item (size_type) VALUES (CAST('small' AS public.size_type))"]
user=>
```